# how to create a vm snapshot using pyvmomi

Tags: vmware, pyvmomi

I have a task of implementing a basic backup and recovery system within a django app. I have heard of pyvmomi, but never used it before.
My specific tasks at hand is:

1)  make a call to a vCenter, pass the vm name, and request to make a snapshot
2)  obtain the file location of the snapshot
3) and upload the snapshot file into an OpenStack Swift object store

What is the actual syntax of creating a vm snapshot using pyvmomi?
Also - what is the syntax to request the actual snapshot file from vCenter?

Comment: Here is a sample to show how to create a snapshot. I uses UUID instead of name though. https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/pull/160

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rreubenur/vmware-pyvmomi-examples/blob/master/create_and_remove_snapshot.py

This should be helpful

Snapshot task result itself contains Moref to snashot created
So that you can get reference to created snapshot.